# Rollout to production, skipping app review?

Tags: android, google-play-console

When clicking the "promote to production" and then clicking the blue "Start rollout to producktion" (this is what I think it is, translated from Danish) I get the following pop-up

[image]

Translated: "This release will be available for all users in Google Play in your chosen countries"

Since this version of the apk has not been reviewed yet, will the the app be released to the play-store immediately, or will it go into review by google?

Comment: it will usually take a few hours until it is live

Comment: Ok, but they might still reject it right?

Comment: They have auomated processes to check your application before going live. If they find something which is against their rules, your app wont make it